# php script sending blank emails not able to fetch post data

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, email

PHP code at the top of index.php. Whenever I click on submit it displays message sent but it generates a blank email to my email address its not catching data from post.

```
<?php   
    $emailSubject = 'Customer Has a Question!';
    $webMaster = 'admin@princosoft.com';
    $name = $_POST['iname'];
    $email = $_POST['iemail'];
    $phone=$_POST['iphone'];
    $question = $_POST['imessage'];
    echo $name;
    $body = <<<EOD
    <br><hr><br>
    Name: $name <br>
    Email: $email <br>
    Questions: $question <br>
    EOD;
    $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);
    $theResults = <<<EOD
    EOD;
    echo "$theResults";
?>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <form name="sentMessage" action="/index.php" method="post" id="contactForm" novalidate >
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="iname" class="form-control" 
                        placeholder="Your Name  *" 
                        id="name"  
                        required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your  name.">
                    <?php  $name = $_POST['iname']; ?>
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" name="iemail" class="form-control" 
                        placeholder="Your Email *" id="email"  
                        required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                        <?php  $name = $_POST['iemail']; ?>
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="tel" name="iphone" 
                        class="form-control" 
                        placeholder="Your Phone *" id="phone"  
                        required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                        <?php  $name = $_POST['iphone']; ?>
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control"name="imessage" placeholder="Your Message *" 
                        id="message"  
                        required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a
                        message.">/textarea>
                    <?php  $name = $_POST['imessage']; ?>
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <div id="success"></div>
                    <button type="submit" name="isubmit" class="btn btn-xl">Send Message</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

This is all the code of html + php

Comment: How you are posting data?

Comment: wait let me add the html code

Comment: html code added @Tushar

Comment: You have syntax error here: `"Please enter a
message.">/textarea>` Not closing `textarea` properly.

Comment: @Rasclatt i did it but the same problem exists .....

Comment: you need some formatting (read indenting) here, lol.

Comment: @Dorvalla aaaaah please the solution its urgent .... i ll get F if this won't resolve :(

Comment: `EOD;` shouldn't be indented...

Comment: Try this..$body = "
<br><hr><br>
Name: $name <br>
Email: $email <br>
Questions: $question <br>
";
$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);

Comment: @PrinceAliRehman - what is the purpose of the `<?php  $name = $_POST['someStringHere']; ?>` statements in the html? You **(a)** dont make use of `$name` and **(b)** asign various different POST variables to it. Are the statements I ask about intended to have some kind of effect?

Comment: @enhzflep it was for checking if the variables are getting values or not but they are not getting any values

Comment: @PrinceAliRehman - how would these check if values are being received?  _I hope you understand that as they are currently, short of using a PHP debugger, there's no way of telling what (if anything) is assigned in them._ If you're not familiar with it, consider looking into and using the `var_dump` function. For instance, `var_dump($_POST);` will show you all data received via POST. Likewise, `var_dump($_GET);` will show you all GET vars, which is only really useful in cases of AJAX, since otherwise, the get vars are visible in the page's url.

Answer (score 0):

Okay just looking at it, there is a lot wrong here.

- First of all, I am not a big fan on EOD. so, I change that to just to quotations.
- Your text needs indenting, seriously, else you cant read it.

Let me first give you the php, then the html.

```
<?php 
    print_r($_POST);  

    if (isset($_POST['isubmit'])){ // checking if the submit button variable is there from clicking on the button
        // mail variables

        $emailSubject = 'Customer Has a Question!';
        $webMaster = 'admin@princosoft.com';
        $name = $_POST['iname'];
        $email = $_POST['iemail'];
        $phone=$_POST['iphone'];  // please note this variable is not used anymore in the code. You either forgot it in your email, or you dont want anything with this
        $question = $_POST['imessage'];

        echo $name;

        //set up mail body
        $body = "<br><hr><br>";
        $body .= "Name:". $name . "<br>";
        $body .= "Email:". $email ."<br>";
        $body .= "Questions:". $question ."<br>";

        $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";

        if (mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers)){
            echo "your mail has been send succesfully";
        }
    } else {
        // this is a test message. Just erase the whole else statement when this all works (for test purposes if the code is read)
        echo "variables aren't set yet"
    }
?>
```

As you see, i did some alterations to your code. I make sure it checks to see if the variables are set up. This way, you can trigger the mail with all variables in it. Now it runs everytime you refresh the page the mail function. You wouldn't wanna do that. I did a check as well on the mailfunction if it has send the messages, and I added an extra header to it.

What you should try to do is sanatize your input. Now it doesn't end up in a database so its not much of a big issue, however, what if you do wanna send it to your own database for reference? Its a simple matter of adding a function called `mysqli_real_escape_string()` (asuming you work with mysqli if you have database functions on your site running. Check that out if you will.

```
<form name="sentMessage" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" id="contactForm" novalidate >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="iname" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name  *" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your  name.">
                    <?php  $name = $_POST['iname']; // i leave this here, but i would remove this. It has no purpose, if you want to replace the name in your field, check if variable is set, and put it in the name field of your item ?>
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="iemail" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                    <?php  $name = $_POST['iemail']; // i leave this here, but i would remove this. It has no purpose, if you want to replace the name in your field, check if variable is set, and put it in the name field of your item ?>
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="tel" name="iphone" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone *" id="phone"  required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                    <?php  $name = $_POST['iphone'];// i leave this here, but i would remove this. It has no purpose, if you want to replace the name in your field, check if variable is set, and put it in the name field of your item  ?>
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control"name="imessage" placeholder="Your Message *" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea> <!-- issue here with wrong closing of text area in html -->
                    <?php  $name = $_POST['imessage']; // i leave this here, but i would remove this. It has no purpose, if you want to replace the name in your field, check if variable is set, and put it in the name field of your item ?>
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <div id="success"></div>
            <button type="submit" name="isubmit" class="btn btn-xl">Send Message</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Also I looked at your html. The key here is called **indenting**. There is some questionable placement of php, which I didnt get. The echo's of the name. If they are checkers, thats fine, removing them in the final product, if they are there to replace the name, you need to add them different. I put in comments how its solvable. (not sure if its wanted, so i left the solution out of the answer, the code you require is already in this answer, you just gotta put some pieces together)

**edit**

I just need to add as well (as interaction designer), that requiring a phonenumber isn't smart, especially when it comes to conversion (how often a client will leave a message) . You want people to contact you. Leaving your phonenumber on the web is something "personal" and it will always bring a person in doubt if people ask for phonenumbers. People dont know what will happen to their phonenumber, so they back out on it. State that information is used carefully.

My tip: dont make the phone field a required field. Just the email, name and message.

Comment: i tried exactly as you said but still its not even generating and email now and still the message sides variables are not set yet, even after i click submit button

Comment: Updated it, i added in the action the php self command, i realized i forgot to put that there. Check if it works now. since you submit it to the same page, the action attribute can be left out or blank, but appearantly it did not. What you wanna do now, is check the post variables. I added in the php code above a line, that shows you all variables that has been pushed by the post method. See if you get a result. Oh and I saw i made a spelling mistake on the `$_POST` variable. That might have been your problem. Check it again